# Why this code get error: "Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation"

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, bots

My code gating error:

```
 File "app.py", line 31
    ed = TwitterBot('Someusername', 'Password@gmail.com')
                                                        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level


i have install 
pip- selenium 
geckodriver
```

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class TwitterBot:
    def **init**(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox()

```
def login(self):
    bot = self.bot
    bot.get('https://twitter.com/')
    time.sleep(3)
    email = bot.find_element_by_class_name('email-input')
    password = bot.find_element_by_name('sesssion[password]')
    email.clear()
    password.clear()
    email.send_keys(self.username)
    password.send_keys(self.password)
    password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(3)

def like_tweet(self, hashtag):
    bot = self.bot
    bot.get = (
        'https://twitter.com/search?q=' + hashtag + '&src=typd')
    time.sleep(3)

 ed = TwitterBot('Someusername', 'Password@gmail.com') #some error
 ed.login()
 ed.like_tweet('webdevelopment')
```

Comment: Because it doesn't. For some reason you have indented the last 3 lines by 1 space each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python relies heavily on indentation think of an indented block as being like enclosing code between '{' and '}' in java say. so it is important to return to exactly the same indent when you leave the block as you had before the block. In this case you don't do that. It looks as though each of the lines beginning 'ed' starts with a space, remove that space and all will be well.